# Flink JDBC UUID – source connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-flink

In Flink 1.15, I want to read a column that is typed with the Postgres UUID type (the `id` column).

However, this does not work; crashes with `The PostgreSQL dialect doesn't support type: RAW('java.lang.String', '...') NOT NULL`. How can I interpret all `id` results as a plain string?

- `DataTypes.STRING()` doesn't work
- `.columnByExpression("id", "CAST(`id `AS VARCHAR(32))")` doesn't work
- `.columnByExpression("id", "\"id\"::varchar")` doesn't work

[image: screenshot of code]

Comment: Facing pretty much the same issue, did you end up figuring this one out?

Comment: Yes @FrankLee - see answer below and don't forget to upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            TableDescriptor.forConnector("jdbc")
                    .schema(
                            Schema.newBuilder()
                                    .column("app_id", DataTypes.STRING().notNull())
                                    .column("moniker", DataTypes.STRING().notNull())
                                    .columnByExpression("a_proctime", "PROCTIME()")
                                    .primaryKey("app_id")
                                    .build())
```

Comment: I'm don't quite understand: The app_id is just a regular string right? In your original post you refer to DataTypes.RAW(String.class)? I can't totally compare, as I'm using SQL.

Comment: Yes, however, there's a long-standing issue on the Flink issue tracker to make this more generic. The RAW didn't work, but when managing treating it as a string on the JVM side, postgres will convert it on its side.